# Getting Control details loaded in Panel dynamically in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a panel in WinForms which loads panels at run time during a method call.

My code looks like:

```
//Adding a child panel
Panel p = new Panel();

//Adding controls to panel
Label lbl5 = new Label();
lbl5.Location = new Point(105, 3);
lbl5.Text = note.noteName;
Label lbl6 = new Label();
lbl6.Location = new Point(105, 43);
lbl6.Text = note.noteName;

p.Controls.Add(lbl5);
p.Controls.Add(lbl6);

//Adding child panel to main panel
Panel1.Controls.Add(p);
```

In this way whenever the method is called a new child panel will be added to main panel.

Can I Click a particular panel which is displayed in main panel ?

I want to get the value of the controls present in selected panel and show it somewhere.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: In this code you didn't add labels to child panel!

Comment: How do you mean select? Do you want to click it, or select it in a loop?

Comment: @Huntt, when user click a child panel, he should get the control values present in it...

Comment: @DigambarMalla As I see you have not accepted any answer in your previous questions yest. You should know here in StackOverflow when a post answers your question, you can kindly click on check mark near that answer to make it accepted. While you can only select one answer as accepted, you can vote for as many answer as you find helpful. You also can vote for good questions. This make questions and answers more useful for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to a event like so:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Click += panel_click;
```

And then create the event:

```
private void panel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel childPanel = sender as Panel;
    foreach(Control c in childPanel.Controls)
    {
        //Do something with you values...
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, let me know if you still run into issues.

Comment: @DigambarMalla Seems like my solution worked out for you, Would you kindly accept this answer as accepted answer? So future readers may benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

Name your panel....

```
var pPanel = new Panel();
pPanel.Name = "pPanel";

// or write it this way....using object initializer
var pPanel = new Panel
{
   Name = "pPanel"
};
```

Then loop through the controls in you master panel for the control you are looking for...

```
 foreach(Control ctrl in mainPanel)
 {
    if (ctrl.Name.Contains("pPanel")) .... then do something etc...; 
 }
```

You can also search for other controls in your panels the same way ...

Comment: Thank u for the solution :)